# Why doesn't my web page update the timer with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, timer, updates, countdown

I am new to JavaScript and am trying to make a timer for a gross words a minute calculator. We have not yet implemented the actual calculator section. The timer is meant to display the time remaining in seconds and minutes. Why does the time not update at all? We've fiddled with updating the elements, but with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

I've made the suggested modifications of

```
seconds_left = document.getElementId("time").value;

if(seconds_left==0){clearInterval();}

seconds_left--;
```

yet the output is not being changed. Why does the timer not change value or update?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function startTimer(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    //inputs
    var seconds_left = document.getElementById("time").value;

    var text = document.getElementById("textfield");

    //variables
    var minutes;

    //get output
    var clock = document.getElementById("timer");

    setInterval(function()
    {
        //seconds mods
        minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
        seconds = seconds_left % 60;

        if(seconds_left == 0)
            clearInterval();

        //output
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        seconds_left--;

    }, 1000);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

Select Time:
<select name="time">
    <option value="30">30 Seconds</option>
    <option value="60">1 Minute</option>
    <option value="180">3 Minutes</option>
    <option value="300">5 Minutes</option>
    <option value="600">10 Minutes"</option>
</select>

<output name="timer">0:00</output>

</br>

<textarea name="textfield" width=600 height=400>Your Text Goes Here </textarea>

<button type="button" onclick="startTimer(event);">Start</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to watch out for when the code executes. Right now you are trying to manipulate the DOM before it has been loaded

Comment: use `onclick="startTimer()"` the event object is passed to the function automatically.

Comment: Err... try your update algorithm with pen and paper... it's never changing its value.

Comment: @Deepak no he's not, he's using a callback

Comment: @Pamblam Ah I didn't spot that

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this several times in your script.

`var seconds_left = document.getElementById("time");`

This returns a DOM object, not it's value. You then try to do math with it, which you can't becuase it's not a number.

What you want is to get the value of the objects, not the objects themselves.

`var seconds_left = document.getElementById("time").value;`

Fix that everywhere by adding the  ".value" part and remove the "event" from the button markup as I explained in the comment and it should work fine.

---

Also, just noticed, you are never actually changing the value. You need to add `seconds_left--;` in your interval function to count the time down.

Comment: Yes, good start, but the algorithm still won't ever update any numbers, just output the same numbers over and over...

Comment: Please don't do a timer in Javascript using `--`. You need to compare a *target time* to the *current time* on each update; otherwise your seconds will drift more and more.

Comment: he can do `if(!seconds_left--){ clearInterval(); }` then, there is absolutely nothing inherently wrong with the way i decremented the value, but I'm not gonna do this kids homework for him.

Answer (score 0):

There where 2 problems with your code that caused it not to work:

1. You need to add an **id attribute for elements** you're trying to grab using `document.getElementById`.

   For example: the select tag should look like this: `<select id="time" name="time">`
2. `clearInterval` function takes as an argument the **id of the interval timer** you intend to cancel. You need to grab the id returned from `setInterval` call.

   For example: start the interval timer using **`var t = setInterval(...)`** and later stop it using **`clearInterval(t)`**.

So your code should look like this in order to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function startTimer(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    //inputs
    var seconds_left = document.getElementById("time").value;

    var text = document.getElementById("textfield");

    //variables
    var minutes, seconds;

    //get output
    var clock = document.getElementById("timer");

    var t = setInterval(function()
    {
        //seconds mods
        minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
        seconds = seconds_left % 60;

        if(seconds_left == 0)
            clearInterval(t);

        //output
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        seconds_left--;

    }, 1000);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

Select Time:
<select id="time" name="time">
    <option value="30">30 Seconds</option>
    <option value="60">1 Minute</option>
    <option value="180">3 Minutes</option>
    <option value="300">5 Minutes</option>
    <option value="600">10 Minutes"</option>
</select>

<output id="timer" name="timer">0:00</output>

</br>

<textarea id="textfield" name="textfield" width=600 height=400>Your Text Goes Here </textarea>

<button type="button" onclick="startTimer(event);">Start</button>

</body>
</html>
```